# Products rearrange feature does not work if you want different orders for multishop PS 1.7.8

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have a multistore and I am using PS 1.7.8. The problem is below.

The order of products changes (the issue is that if someone changes the order on a shop X, it changes the order of the shop Y as well. So this issue is related to the multi-shop feature)

Can anyone help me to resolve this bug?

Thanks in Advance

the issue is that if someone changes the order on a shop X, it changes the order of the shop Y as well. So this issue is related to the multi-shop feature. I want the order of products in shop X different then on Y shop.